# The type or namespace platform does not exist in the name space MvvmCross.Forms

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I followed the TipCalc tutorial as recommended in the mvvmcross documentation
[Here](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/tutorials/tipcalc/a-xamarin-forms-version), The Core project and UI project works perfectly. But the android MainActivity has errors as it cannot find the namespace

```
MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Android.Core
MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Android.Views
```

Everything appears right but i am unable to figure out what i am doing wrong.

I have installed:

```
      MvvmCross 6.1.2
      MvvmCross.Forms 6.0.1.0
      Xamarin.Forms 3.1.0.583944
```

I use TargetFrameWork 8.1 (Oreo)and .net Standard 2.0
I also confirmed in the MvvmCross GitHub repository that the namespace exists.

Here is a peek at

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using TipCalc.Core;
using TipCalc.Forms.UI;
using MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Android.Core;
using MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Android.Views;

namespace TipCalc.Forms.Droid
{
    [Activity(
        Label = "TipCalc.Forms.Droid",
        Icon = "@drawable/icon",
        Theme = "@style/MyTheme",
        MainLauncher = true,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask)]
    public class MainActivity : MvxFormsAppCompatActivity<MvxFormsAndroidSetup<App, FormsApp>, App, FormsApp>
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the error

[image: Here is a Screenshot of the error message]

Comment: Screenshot of the error looks a lot like screenshot of the code instead, but anyhow, add the error as text, not images.

Comment: Try a clean solution, rebuild and restart of Visual Studio

Comment: I have tried all that, it doesn't work @Salvatore'Lucky'Luciano

Comment: @manasera try Update-Package -reinstall in your nuget package console

Comment: Having the exact same problem. (REALLY frustrating as I've also tried all of these suggestions to no avail.) Did you ever get it figured out?

Answer (score 1):

Your MvvmCross and MvvmCross.Forms packages are not in sync. They need to be the same version.

Easiest way is to go to the NuGet Package Manager for the solution in VS for Windows and consolidate the packages through the consolidate tab.

If you can't do that you can uninstall the packages, then re-install them.

Comment: Tried un-install, re-install. No joy.  :(

Comment: Yeah I'm having the same problem and have tried all the suggestions here.